# Building a string with comma separated values

Tags: java, sql, string, stringbuilder

For the purpose of building a database system I am using a simple builder to generate selection query based on user choices. It has a couple of booleans and then it progresses as follows

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("SELECT ");
    if(addOpen)
        builder.append("Open ");
    if(addHigh)
        builder.append("High ");
    if(addLow)
        builder.append("Low ");
    if(addSettle)
        builder.append("Settle ");
    builder.append("FROM " + tableName);
```

Now, my problem is trivial - I need to include commas but if I include a comma there must be a value coming after it, so I cannot do Open, or Open, Close,  etc. Is there a neat solution to this trivial, yet surprisingly hard for me problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick I use (in a generic semi-untyped pseudo-code) is:

```
 pad = ""    # Empty string

 builder = "SELECT ";
 if (addOpen)
     builder += pad + "Open";   pad = ", ";
 if (addHigh)
     builder += pad + "High";   pad = ", ";
 if (addLow)
     builder += pad + "Low";    pad = ", ";
 if (addSettle)
     builder += pad + "Settle"; pad = ", ";
 builder += "FROM " + TableName;
```

An alternative I've seen is to always include the comma (or comma space) after the terms, but trim the last two characters off the value before adding the FROM clause.  Your choice...the 'pad' technique works even if you're doing output and can't undo an append.

Comment: Broken. You need braces around the if bodies.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like [Apache Commons' StringUtils.join()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Iterable,%20char%29) methods? I.e:

```
Collection<String> selections = Arrays.asList("Open", "Low");
String clause = StringUtils.join(selections, ',');
```

Then just

```
String sql = "SELECT " + clause + " FROM " + TableName;
```

Answer (score 3):

1) the typical case is you know a priori how many items you have.  So you just loop "n-1", then don't append a comma to the last item.

2) One possible solution:

```
  ArrayList<string> items = new ArrayList<String>();
  if(addOpen);
    items.add("Open ");
  if(addHigh)
    items.add("High ");
  if(addLow)
    items.add("Low ");
  if(addSettle)
    items.add("Settle ");

  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  int i=0;
  for (i=0; i < items.size() - 1; i++) {
    builder.append(items[i] + ",");
  }
  builder.append(items[i] + "FROM " + tableName);
  ...
```

Comment: It will add "," at the end of last string

Answer (score 1):

There is a common trick: Select always a constant, which you aren't interested in:

```
builder.append ("SELECT 1 ");
if (addOpen)
    builder.append (", Open ");
if addHigh)
    builder.append (", High ");
if (addLow)
    builder.append (", Low ");
if (addSettle)
    builder.append (", Settle ");
builder.append ("FROM " + tableName);
```

An alternative approach works in the other direction, with trailing commas:

```
builder.append ("SELECT ");
if (addOpen)
    builder.append ("Open, ");
if (addHigh)
    builder.append ("High, ");
if (addLow)
    builder.append ("Low, ");
if (addSettle)
    builder.append ("Settle, ");
builder.append ("1 FROM " + tableName);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways.  The first, which would be my first choice, is don't build your SQL statement at all, and just don't display the fields.

The second is, build the string, and just remove the last comma.

The third is to put each field name into an array, and loop through the array, not putting the trailing comma on the last element.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation I use a solution similarto that suggested by Ryan Stewart, but I prefer Google [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) instead of Apache Commons. I prefer this library because I feel that Apache libraries are to gigantic and interlinked.
Here below is how I would build your SQL string:

```
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;
import com.google.common.base.Strings;
import java.util.List;

public class SqlJoiner {
    public String buildSql(
            boolean addOpen,
            boolean addHigh,
            boolean addLow,
            boolean addSettle,
            String tableName
    ) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(tableName));
        Preconditions.checkArgument(addOpen | addHigh | addLow | addSettle );

        final List<String> clauses = Lists.newArrayList();

        if (addOpen) clauses.add("Open");
        if (addHigh) clauses.add("High");
        if (addLow) clauses.add("Low");
        if (addSettle) clauses.add("Settle");

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT ");
        builder.append(Joiner.on(',').join(clauses));
        builder.append(" FROM " + tableName);
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

The precondition at the start of the method body are meant to be sure that at least one of the boolean option is always true, and that tableName is not null or empty. Always check for precondition of your code, it will save you lot of trouble when you'll make mistakes using your code in the future!